# The Quadratic Residues/Nonresidues of modulo 15

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In an effort to determine these, I crafted the following table mod 15.
[image]

In turn the answer is given to be: [image]

Since a quadratic residue is said to be an integer q such that  $x^2 \equiv q\mod 15 $, if there exists an integer between 0 and 15 that is in the second row of my table, shouldn't it be a quadratic residue?

Additionally, I had thought that all integers within that range were either residues or nonresidues, whereas this answer omits those I would have expected to be residues but which were not.

Have I fundamentally misunderstood the concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual definition of a quadratic residue modulo $m$ is a number $a$ **relatively prime** to $m$ which is congruent to a square modulo $m$.

The quadratic non-residues of $m$ are the numbers $a$ relatively prime to $m$ which are not congruent to a square.

Up to congruence modulo $m$, we can confine attention to the numbers in the interval $[0,m-1]$. But because they are not relatively prime to $m$, the numbers $0,3,5,6,9,10,12$ are not even in the game: they are neither QR nor NR.

Comment: Thanks! 

Unfortunately, some of the first websites to come up confused the matter by contradicting that definition, thus leading to the question.
http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/QuadraticResidue.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue

Comment: You are right, I would not have believed that anyone would count $0$ as a quadratic residue of a prime. If you look at any serious book, or Internet site, that will not happen.